# Any trick to type ¿ in a US keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, international, spanish

I have a US-International keyboard layout but often need to type spanish characters, almost all can be easily replaced with a key combination, except `¿` that I need to pull out Win-. to select the character.

Anyone knows a key combination to type it easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I type ¿ using a US International keyboard layout?

Use <kbd>right</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>

Source: [Typing Spanish Characters - Spanish411](https://www.spanish411.net/Spanish-Typing-Special-Characters.asp#WindowsIntlKeyboard)

Comment: Yes! Additionaly you can `right-alt-1` to get `¡`